# Add Peers does not add a peer in Geth console

Tags: ethereum, geth

I am trying to add a peer. I created two nodes using the following commands on geth.The boot node creation command is

```
geth --datadir ./chaindata3 --port 30304 --nodiscover --networkid 12 --rpc --rpcport "8546" --rpccorsdomain "*" --ipcdisable console
```

The other node creation command

```
geth --datadir ./chaindata4 --port 30307 --nodiscover --networkid 12 --ipcdisable --bootnodes "enode://7143091f47a3d4aae216ce781e28b53c1faa9daa08bbeaa9a01adbd9b3933fb3b83acff00a375bf0a4b30b1135b7aabef422c28c60279de34e9399a3d91d7c88@127.0.0.1:30304" console
```

When i type the command admin.peers it returns an empty list. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup actual boot node, don't treat base node (first full node as boot node).

```
bootnode -genkey boot.key

bootnode -addr localhost:port -nodekey boot.key  -verbosity 9
```

Start other nodes pointing the boot node

**ex:**

```
geth --datadir "data" --syncmode "full" --rpcport port --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost"  --port port --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "personal,eth,net,db,web3,txpool,miner" --bootnodes "enode://************@localhost:port" --networkid 100  --ipcdisable --mine console
```

*Sorry couldn't format:that's why added new answer*

Comment: The first two commands of setting up  a bootnode on which terminal should I type it.

Comment: It is just as similar to other nodes, but it only acts as a message broker.
In one terminal run the boot node command.
In another terminal initialize and start the nodes, with verbose enabled you can able to see the logs how node communicate in the boot node terminal.

Comment: But bootnode is not a command right It shows no command found.

Answer (score 0):

Both the nodes should be initiated with the same genesis.
Starting Geth directly without initializing it with the genesis creates a block with default networkId and consensus algorithm which will not be the same as the base genesis.

Comment: Actually I did that but whenever i am using rpc port im facing a problem without rpc it just works fine and shows peers

Comment: Setup actual boot node, don't treat base node (first full node as boot node).
**bootnode -genkey boot.key**






**bootnode -addr localhost:port -nodekey boot.key  -verbosity 9**

Start other nodes pointing the boot node

**ex:**
geth --datadir "data" --syncmode "full" --rpcport port --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost"  --port port --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "personal,eth,net,db,web3,txpool,miner" --bootnodes "enode://************@localhost:port" --networkid 100  --ipcdisable --mine console

_Sorry couldn't format_